# Can I temporarily disable all vim-like keybinding?

Tags: insert-mode

I use vim for editing everything. Occasionally while I have vim open someone else will want to write something for me. (My coworkers explaining code, friends helping me write something/leaving notes for me, etc.) As I'm sure you all know, vim isn't exactly, uhm *Intuitive* to people who have never used it before.

As soon as they start typing, I watch the visible panic on their face as they realize my text editor is the text editing equivalent of [the sonic screwdriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_screwdriver). They have no idea what's happening, and it's flashing, my text is deleted and they've accidentally opened 2 help buffers and the command line history.

Can I make vim act like every other boring text editor for a little while? I know about vim's *easy mode*:

```
                            *-y* *easy*
-y      Easy mode.  Implied for |evim| and |eview|.  Starts with
        'insertmode' set and behaves like a click-and-type editor.
        This sources the script $VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim.  Mappings are
        set up to work like most click-and-type editors, see
        |evim-keys|.  The GUI is started when available.
        {not in Vi}
```

But this doesn't help me because it's only a startup option. I'd love to have a way to keep all my old files open, press a key-combination, and have all vim-like bindings disappear until I press it a second time.

Is there any existing plugin for this? If not, what settings/features should I look into if I were to write my own?

Comment: It looks like you could start from evim.vim and mswin.vim. If it may help you, I have a very old (vim 5.4 era, IIRC) and clumsy plugin able to toggle the activation state of mappings and other things it may be a starting point: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/Triggers.vim

Comment: Could you not just put it in insert mode? As long as they don't press escape it'll behave like notepad for anything they would need for a short editing session.

Comment: `:!nano %` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If if has to be the same editor, I would go with `:set insertmode`. This basically switches to the mentioned *easy mode*, even `<Esc>` won't do harm. Leave again with `<C-O>:set noinsertmode<CR>`.

However, I would instead allow your colleague to open the text file in a different editor of his choosing. Just `:write` any unpersisted changes, and open it elsewhere in parallel. Settings like `:set autoread` make this even more comfortable.

I personally often edit / browse the same files in GVIM and an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). You could even facilitate this with a custom `:OpenWith` command within Vim. In a graphical environment, it's easy to open another editor; it's only clumsy if you only have a single SSH terminal connection; you'd block your Vim unless you open another connection or use a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`.